# Escape from JUnit testcase possible?

Tags: java, junit, escaping, testcase

Is it possible to escape from a JUnit testcase (maybe via reflection) and to modify the test result?

Let's say we have a method

```
int foo() { ... }
```

which is under test and a method

```
void fooTest() { ... }
```

which tests `foo()` for correct implementation.

Is it somehow possible to cheat in `foo()` and to access (maybe via the stack trace and reflection) the test method / result so the test doesn't fail even when `foo` is incorrect?

Comment: Could you expand as to why you would want this? Perhaps your problem is of the X-Y kind.

Comment: We want to grade student exercises with JUnit. If there is a way to work around the test cases (aka. to cheat) we have to avoid that somehow.

Comment: Why would this matter? It's not like students have access to the source code, how would this influence the program? I guess you could decompile it and recompile it, but surely you can counter the cheating by simply storing every student's answers in a central database? I wouldn't do the verifying of results on the client's side, critical purposes like that are best kept safe serverside.

Comment: Students don't get access to the source code, also tests are executed on our server side. But better safe than sorry: we don't like security by obscurity but real security. So, the question is: can students modify the result **with reflection** (or similar) not in the source.

Answer (score 1):

`@Ignore` is used to temporarily disable a test:

```
@Ignore 
@Test 
public void testMethod() { // enter code here }
```

Reason can also be provided which is optional:

```
@Ignore("Under development") 
@Test 
public void testMethod() { // enter code here }
```

`@Ignore` can be used at class level:

```
@Ignore 
public class IgnoreTestClass {
      @Test public void testOne(){`enter code here`}
      @Test public void testTwo(){`enter code here`}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If created these `testcases` in anotner `JUnit classes`, you can run these in `TestSuite` class. It can adjust wich `JUnit class` run in `TestSuite`.

Comment: That was not my question. The question is: can the system/method under test escape and change the test case result?